# Calling FancyBox from custom menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a custom menu with a fixed position that allows users to navigate through [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox). It all works fine, except the part that the animation effects (those you have when you navigate through FancyBox by clicking the images) do not apply to the menu.

What do I have to do to get it working?

**http://jsfiddle.net/PwMjP/866**

FancyBox settings:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({

    wrapCSS       : 'fancybox-custom-white',
    closeClick    : false,
    topRatio      : 0,
    scrolling     : 'no',
    width         : '100%',
    padding       : '0',
    fitToView     : false,
    transitionIn  : 'elastic',
    transitionOut : 'elastic',
    speedIn       : 600, 
    speedOut      : 200, 
    overlayShow   : false,
    nextMethod    : 'changeIn',
    nextSpeed     : 250,
    prevMethod    : false,

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
        $(".fancybox").click(function(){
        $(".menu-content").css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,0.95)');

        });
```

P.S.: Would be great if anyone could post some working code or a fiddle. Thanks!